# run-length-decoder formatting -not list to str issue

Tags: python

I'm working on a run-length-decoder that's able to accept a list with an encoded sequence, and return the decoded string. The following code works if I input 'qaa4bb2cc3d'  → for an output like this 'qaaaabbcccd' but doesn't work for this format ['q', 'a', 'a', 4, 'b', 'b', 2, 'c', 'c', 3, 'd']  → 'qaaaabbcccd' (separate quotation marks and commas)
I end up with an error like this: "TypeError:can only concatenate str (not "list") to str" I think it has to do with the formatting of giving a list or string, how should I solve this problem in order for my code to work?

```
def decode(in_list):
    if len(in_list) < 3:
        return in_list

    char1 = in_list[0]
    char2 = in_list[1]
    num = in_list[2]


    if num.isdigit():
        return char1 * int(num) + decode(in_list[3:])
    else:
        return char1 + decode(in_list[1:])
```

Comment: those are two different datatypes one is a string and another is a list. you may want to check if it is a list and transform it to a string like so: `if isinstance(in_list, list):` then `in_list = "".join(in_list)`

Comment: I implemented your method in my code but now there's a new problem. I also have numbers/integers inside the list so it doesn't go through when transforming it into a string.

Comment: @ChengYANG楊誠--to fix that problem you could use `"".join(map(str,in_list))` to ensure all elements are strings as required by the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your parameter to a string and use it as it is. Do this at the beginning of your function:

```
in_list = "".join(map(str, in_list))
```

So that it will work for all *iterable*s. It doesn't matter if it is `str`, `list` or `tuple`.